# код ничего не выводит, уже пробовал и менять значения, но мне кажется что то не так с lru_cache но не могу понять что

Tags: python

```
import sys
from functools import *
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)


@lru_cache(maxsize=100)
def f(n):
    if n>=2025:
        return n
    if n<2025: 
        return f(n+1) - f(n+2)+7
print(f(15)-f(24))
```

Comment: У меня выводит `<built-in method cache_info of functools._lru_cache_wrapper object at 0x7fe5e53a3060>` как и должно. В чём проблема?

Comment: прошу прощения я перепутал последние строки, вот что должно быть в конце print(f(15)-f(24))

Comment: Теперь выводит RecursionError из-за запредельной рекурсии (опять же как и должно)

Comment: но у меня выводит абсолютно пустую консоль, без ошибки

Comment: Значит какие-то проблемы с вашей консолью

Comment: да, оказалось вы правы, спасибо<3

Answer (score 2):

С `lru_cache` всё нормально, проблема в том, как у вас вычисляется очередной элемент. Эта проблема называется `n+1`, если я ничего не путаю. Для того, чтобы вычислить `f(n)` вам нужны значения `f(n+1)` и `f(n+2)`. Сначала вычисляется `f(n+1)`, для вычисления которого нужны значения `f(n+2)` и `f(n+3)` и т.д. Т.е. кэш вообще не имеет возможности сработать - вам всё время нужны элементы, которых в нём ещё нет, функция продолжает вызывать сама себя (да ещё и по два раза за один её вызов) до тех пор, пока не исчерпается допустимый уровень рекурсии.

Но есть одна хитрость, которая может заставить ваш код работать. Если вы предварительно вызовете вашу функцию в обратном порядке по убывающей, то кэш будет при этом эффективно задействован для вычисления очередных элементов, да и нужные вам элементы там тоже запомнятся. Такой код отработает моментально и без проблем:

```py
for i in range(2025, 0, -1):
    f(i)
print(f(15)-f(24))
# 4036
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но вопрос был не об этом)